# Making MySQL connection global in python

Tags: python, global-variables, mysql-connector

How to make MySQL connection global in python.Does adding connection.close() on every function makes the connection stand still if global is declared outside.

I tried to declare connection global outside but unfortunately got a page full error and I was satisfied. The error highlight like (Unread result found)

Comment: Generally when requesting help you should include the code you have written and any relevant stack traces.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.